# Why is usb-c usb V3.1 and not V4.0?

Tags: usb, version

Like the title says. Why is the new USB type C version 3.1? I thought version names went major.minor.micro. USB C is **not** backwards compatible with USB-A without a converter so doesn't this make USB-C V4.0 since its a major upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why is USB-C V3.1 and not V4.0?

The new USB type C specification is version 1.0 **not** 3.1.

> The USB 3.1 standard is backward compatible with USB 3.0 and USB 2.0.
>
> **The USB Type-C Specification 1.0 defines a new small reversible-plug
>   connector for USB 3.1 devices.** The type-C plug will be used at both
>   host and device side, replacing multiple type-B and type-A connectors
>   and cables with a future-proof standard similar to Apple Lightning and
>   Thunderbolt.

Source [USB 3.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_3.1)

---

#### Where can I find the USB Type-C Specification Release 1.0?

See [USB Type-C Specification Release 1.0](https://archive.org/stream/pdfy-b57BTnAHh_rUeXBf/USB%20Type-C%20Specification%20Release%201.0_djvu.txt) for the specification.

---

#### USB-C is not backwards compatible with USB-A

USB C **replaces** multiple type-B and type-A connectors and cables.

Comment: I knew that USB-C replaced Type-A and B. This is why I thought that it should be USB V4.0 however USB-C is still V3.1 isn't it? Sorry if I am not understanding you, its just that I need it explained a bit more. Thank you for answering though.

Comment: Because it's the very same protocol? It's just a different physical connector, much like PCIe is the same over Mini-PCIe and a regular-sized slot.

Comment: So USB 3.1 allows audio and video out as well as allowing 100W of power in both directions?

Comment: @aPyDeveloper I can’t quite follow. USB is still USB. It’s the same protocol, whatever connector (A, B, Mini, Micro) you’re using. What makes you think C is incompatible (other than mechanically, of course) with the other form factors?

Comment: There is one standard (specification) for the USB protocol itself (currently at 3.1). There is another different standard (specification) for USB C connectors, currently at 1.0 (because it is new).

Comment: @DanielB That is what I mean. USB-C also has video and audio out which I do not think the other USB protocol has.

Comment: @aPyDeveloper You sure you’re not confusing Alt Mode for USB? Because it isn’t USB. Just because there’s serial connectors with RJ45 doesn’t mean serial is the new Ethernet.

Comment: @DanielB This is what I mean. http://www.pcworld.com/article/2686892/reversible-usb-type-c-wonder-cable-will-deliver-displayport-audio-and-video-too.html. That whats new in USB-C

Comment: @aPyDeveloper that is DisplayPort technology. Just because a cable is labeled USB doesn't mean it can't be used for something else. It's still a USB 3.1 compatible cable, constructed to a USB C 1.0 standard. **DisplayPort technology** has nothing to do with USB, it just works over the same cable.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Just did some more research. There is usb 3.1 type-a and type-c. Sorry to waste some of your time.